# ADFS cookies not getting clear after successful logout

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs2.0

we are  using ADFS for SSO , 
when we successful logging out from our app using this URL 
https://XXXXX/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignout1.0
we deleting all application level cookies , but once user clicking on back buttion in browser its  user able to login in application again . 
[image]

we can see there some ADFS related cookies which we cant delete from app.
any suggestion to solve this issue .

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong endpoint for the logout. The endpoint for SAML logout is:
https://XXXXX/adfs/ls/{your_saml_logout_request}. The endpoint with "?wa=wsignout1.0" is for ws-federation logout and doesn't actually clears the cookie for the SAML login session. To get the SAML logout working do check your hashing algorithm matches for the SP and the ADFS. Also, your logout request should be signed.

Comment: what is expected here: "{your_saml_logout_request}" ?

Comment: saml logout request body in the form of xml

Comment: Can you please describe in details, like is it a parameter of the url ? is it GET or POST? only assertion id is expected or entire assertion?
we are struggling to get it done. We have configured HTTP-POST binding for logout. Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. Now I am clearing my Azure AD auth cookies like this. Maybe its not the best solution, but it works

```
 while (Request.Cookies["MyCookie"] != null && Request.Cookies["MyCookie1"] != null)
        {
            Request.Cookies["MyCookie"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5);
            Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("MyCookie"));
            Request.Cookies["MyCookie1"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5);
            Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("MyCookie1"));                
        }
```

Comment: Cookies assigned by ADFS are set for different path, usually /adfs. Logout service of application may not receive ADFS cookies.